# Secure way to connect power bi to azure cosmos db

Tags: powerbi, azure-cosmosdb

Currently I am connecting to cosmos db by providing endpoint url in get data menu of power bi desktop application. Endpoint url is taken from azure portal's cosmos db -> key section. Is there any other secure way to connect?

Comment: What you described is exactly what microsoft recommends for these services. Is there a particular reason you're looking for something different? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/powerbi-visualize

Comment: I don't want to keep connection string in readable format for security reasons. This way we can easily read the connection string by clicking 'Recent sources' button on home page of Power BI desktop.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may try out is that store the key in [`Azure Keyvault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/access-secrets-from-keyvault), then you can use the Azure [`key vault rest Api`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret/getsecret) to access those secret from the PowerBI.

However i did see the support for [BYOK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-encryption-byok) functionality of PowerBI, but this is specific with how PowerBI encrypts data at rest.